# The unofficial name of the product before the release

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say a company is developing a product and they call it somehow internally, but that name will change in the future if the product is released. The general word for that is **temporal name**, but I am looking for a more specific professional term.

> For the last 5 years they have been working on a project with the _____(temporal name) "ABC", which was released a few months ago under the title of "ZXY".

Comment: Personally I would not use "temporal" in a context like this. "Temporal" has other senses - as well as its rare use as a synonym of **"temporary"** e.g. as an opposite to "spiritual" or "religious".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what is your job. In some sectors **working title** may fit your needs.

**working title** ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_title))

> A working title, sometimes called a production title, is the temporary
>   title of a product or project used during its development, usually
>   used in filmmaking, television production, novel, video game
>   development, or music album.

Answer (score 0):

"Working name"

[ZDNet](https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-has-lightweight-collaboration-project-management-mobile-apps-in-the-works/)

> Microsoft also is believed to be working on a lightweight collaboration and document-sharing app (which may be using "Flip" as its working name)

[Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/article/urnidgns852573c400693880002576f0005f3e02-idUS364161644220100324)

> The new software hasn’t been officially given a name yet, though Microsoft’s official working name is Communications Server ‘14.’